# is this the right way of working with forms in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I wanted to know if this code is well raised. It is a form whose action is another page other than the current one, and for this I had to define another form on the action page. It sounds a bit strange to me to have to define another form in the action page (in app_lucky_number) so I ask this question. I wanted to know if it is the correct way to work with forms in symfony.
This is the defaultController:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use AppBundle\Form\GenusFormType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use AppBundle\Entity\Genus;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */

public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $gen=new Genus;
    $form = $this->createForm(GenusFormType::class,$gen,array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('app_lucky_number'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form->handleRequest($request);      
    return $this->render('genus/new.html.twig', [           
        'genusForm' => $form->createView()         
    ]);
} 

}
?>
```

and this is the action page (app_lucky_number)

```
<?php 
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use AppBundle\Form\GenusFormType;

class LuckyController extends Controller
{
/**
* @Route("lucky/number/", name="app_lucky_number")    
*/
public function number(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(GenusFormType::class);     
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {               
        $genus = $form->getData();        
        $name=$genus->getName();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();        
        $em->persist($genus);        
        $em->flush();      
        return $this->render('genus/principal.html.twig',array('name'=>$name));    
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: I believe yes this is what official docs recommend to have a form class using form builder

Comment: Yep.  Both Get and Post handlers have to create the form.  Which is why you would normally do this inside of the same method.  But what you have is fine.  It's really only one line of duplicate code.  If it was more complicated or if even the one line bothers you then you could extract that line and share it between the controllers.  Probably not worth the effort.

Comment: a few things: in your first method, you can replace `$gen` with `null` in the `createForm` call, you can omit `'method' => 'POST'` since it's the default. since you split the receiving end into another route, the `action` entry is actually required, the `handleRequest(...)` however is not (since there's never any data to process at that point). in your second method, you have to return a response in case the form has an error (probably the same stuff as in your first method, which is why usually people put those into one method) ... i.e. the else branch. apart from that it's fine. ;o)